# MS SQL результирующая строка как часть имени столбца

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте.
Такой вопрос. Необходимо такой результат запроса:

```
ID_OWNER | NUM_MEETING | NUM_QUESTION | NUM_TYPEVOTE
xxx      | 4           | 15           | 1
yyy      | 4           | 15           | 1
yyy      | 4           | 17           | 0
```

Представить в виде:

```
ID_OWNER | NUM_MEETING | NUM_TYPEVOTE15 | NUM_TYPEVOTE17
xxx      | 4           | 1              | NULL
yyy      | 4           | 1              | 0
```

Возможно, нужно использовать оператор PIVOT, но моих знаний не хватило.

Comment: Откуда эти результаты для `NUM_TYPEVOTE15` и `NUM_TYPEVOTE17`? Не понимаю, какую связь ожидаете между первыми результатами и последными?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не уточнил. В NUM_TYPEVOTE15 и NUM_TYPEVOTE17  цифры в названии это значения из первого результата в столбце NUM_QUESTION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
;WITH src AS (
-- тут ваш запрос
    SELECT ID_OWNER, NUM_MEETING, NUM_QUESTION, NUM_TYPEVOTE FROM SomeTable
)
SELECT ID_OWNER, NUM_MEETING, [15] AS NUM_TYPEVOTE15, [17] AS NUM_TYPEVOTE17
    FROM src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(NUM_TYPEVOTE) -- замените на нужный агрегат, по трем строчкам тяжело угадать
    FOR NUM_QUESTION  IN
    ( [15], [17] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY ID_OWNER, NUM_MEETING
```

"совсем динамически" сделать не получится - PIVOT требует указания конкретных значений, которые надо превращать в столбцы. Если нужна совсем динамика - лучше делать ее постпроцессингом в вызывающем коде.